# Do template classes and template functions cause code bloating?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I've been coding some container classes from scratch and I've been using templates so that the containers can handle different data types. However, most of the functions in these classes are only concerned with low level operations in terms of moving blocks of data around, and it isn't always necessary to know about the operations on the data types themselves (You pretty much just need to know their size). The use of templates in this instance seems like it would cause code bloating, unless an optimizing compiler can somehow generalize a function template for all data types.

Does the Standard Template Library take code bloating into account? For example, if I use a vector of ints and a vector of chars in my C++ program, is the compiler going to generate two copies of the vector class (One for int and one for char)?

Comment: Compare *"(You pretty much just need to know their size)"* and *"(One for int and one for char)"*. Note that `int` and `char` very likely have different sizes. Your example does not support your argument for merging function implementations. Maybe your example should involve "pointer to int" and "pointer to char", as those types do have the same size?

Comment: What's your measure of "code bloating"??  Your "low-level" approach may or may not reduce code, but a key compromise will be type safety (i.e. which makes it harder getting your code working *correctly* on all types).   On your `vector<int>` and `vector<char>` query - it depends.  Most implementations only generate code for operations you *use* and some then use both compile-time and link-time inlining approaches to optimise a lot of that small fraction of code out of existence.

Comment: The compiler is likely to inline most of it anyway.

Comment: I'm saying you could generalize some container functions by just storing the size of the object in a runtime variable (int is 4 bytes, char is 1 byte) and then use that one function. Rather than generating two different functions for int and for char.

Comment: libstdc++ for example has non-templated base classes or members for most of its containers which hold common implementations details

Comment: The proper operation of a vector depends on type-specific things like assignment, copying, move semantics, construction, destruction, ... I suspect that you haven't tested your implementations with anything more interesting than primitive types.